# Separation of distinct numbered Blue ball

Tags: combinatorics

Five distinct balls numbered $B_1,B_2,B_3,B_4$ and $B_5$ are arranged such that balls of consecutive numbers are separated . How many possible arrangements are there?

Manually I am able to do up to certain extent

$B_3B_5B_2B_4B_1$  & $B_1B_4B_2B_5B_3$ is one of the example where in consecutive number balls are separated.

Comment: @N. F. Taussig Can you help me with this question, I saw your approach is tremendous

Comment: Not sure if there is a nice formula, but you should be able to do this by hand with little effort. Can you show us some more effort? If you can find an arrangement with $B_1$ at the end, surely you can find some arrangements that has $B_1$ not at the end!

Comment: I am sure Inclusion Exclusion Formula will work but it is complicated

Comment: @SamarImamZaidi yes inclusion exclusion will work

Comment: http://oeis.org/A002464

Comment: When you try the Inclusion-Exclusion Principle, notice that consecutive numbers within a block can only be arranged in ascending or descending order.

Comment: Please edit your question to include your own attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For 5 nodes, it easier to visualize on an allowed neighbors graph and count the Hamiltonian paths. Due to symmetry you just need to consider 3 nodes as the starting point.

[image]